# Insert data in table, update other table with FK in one query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have one Table A with 3 attributes:

**ID (PK), UNIT(varchar2), VALUE(number)**

And I have another Table B that references the PK of Table A via a foreign key.

**ID, FK_TABLE_A**

In Table B are already records, but the value of the attribute **FK_TABLE_A** is null. What I want is, that all records in Table B get an **own unique reference** to Table A's PK by inserting new data into Table A and referencing the newly created primary key as foreign key into Table B.

What I have done so far:
I can now insert new data via following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A(ID, UNIT, VALUE) VALUES (TABKE_A_SEQ.nextval, 'SOME_STRING', 1);
```

And I can update by hand the refernce to Table B

```
UPDATE TABLE_B SET FK_TABLE_A = 123; //123 is just an example PK
```

But I do not want to query for each record everytime the DB, but instead want to combine somehow the first `insert` with the second `update` in one query. 
So that the update takes the newly created PK in Table A as reference.

Is this possible?

I am using Oracle as DB.

Comment: Do you just mean using `TABKE_A_SEQ.currval` insteadof `123` in your update? How do you know which rows in table B to update if there is no PK/FK relationship yet?

Comment: your TABLE_B is referencing TABLE_A. How do you know which child row to update?. If it is an insert in TABLE_A, it should also be an insert in TABLE_B, not update.

Comment: Each record in Table_B should get a different foreign key of course. (Which is the primary key of the freshly created entry in Table A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've used the sequence in your session, you can [use the `currval` pseudocolumn](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Sequence-Pseudocolumns.html) to get the last sequence value issued in your session, by the last `nextval` call:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A(ID, UNIT, VALUE) VALUES (TABKE_A_SEQ.nextval, 'SOME_STRING', 1);
UPDATE TABLE_B SET FK_TABLE_A = TABKE_A_SEQ.currval;
```

(Although as you don't have a filter, that will update all rows in table B to the same FK value; presumably you're doing something more complicated to identify the relevant rows...)

---

If you want a one-to-one relationship and don't care which row gets which PK value, and you can make the constraint deferrable, you could approach it the other way around; update all the table B rows using the sequence, then create the table A rows using those.

With a quick demo table:

```
create table table_a (id number primary key, unit varchar2(20), value number);
create table table_b (id number,
  fk_table_a number references table_a(id) initially deferred deferrable);
create sequence table_a_seq;
create sequence table_b_seq start with 50;

insert into table_b (id) select table_b_seq.nextval from dual connect by level <= 5;
```

Then, in a single transaction, update all the rows and do a single insert:

```
update table_b set fk_table_a = table_a_seq.nextval;

insert into table_a (id, unit, value)
select fk_table_a, 'SOME_STRING', 1
from table_b;
```

The constraint has to be deferrable to allow the update to happen first; otherwise you'd get ORA-02291.

If the unit/value are coming from `table_a` you can include those in the query instead of using fixed literals. It's hard to tell what you actually need for those, and you said they could even be left null.

Now you have:

```
select * from table_a;

        ID UNIT                      VALUE
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 SOME_STRING                   1
         2 SOME_STRING                   1
         3 SOME_STRING                   1
         4 SOME_STRING                   1
         5 SOME_STRING                   1

select * from table_b;

        ID FK_TABLE_A
---------- ----------
        50          1
        51          2
        52          3
        53          4
        54          5
```

Comment: This would create only one entry in Table_A. I wanted to create for each record in Table B a new entry in Table A and reference this newly created PK from TABLE_A in TABLE_B

Comment: How do you decide which row(s) in table B get which PK/FK value? Are you pulling a value from table B out into a separate table and want to refer back to that? (e.g. unit and value currently exist in B but are duplicated?) Also you make it sound like a one-to-one relationship; if that is the case, why split the data across two tables?

Comment: Yes it is a one to one relationship. I decided to split it, because TABLE_B has already a lot of attributes (and is not explicitly used by TABLE B). Table_B should get the immediately created PK value of the created entry in Table A, that's why I thought of a one-shot command :)

Comment: OK.. then where are the unit and value coming from, are they columns in table B at the moment?

Comment: You can leave these values null, or at a dummy value. I am only interested in the created PK.

Comment: I'm not sure splitting with a one-to-one relationship is a good idea - you're just introducing a join and more work for the DB whenever you need to get the data, for little benefit. But maybe you have a real need for some reason. If you have a lot of attribute columns, it might be more sensible to instead have a table that has one row for each ID/attribute pair, with its value. Depends what you're actually doing of course, just a thought.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that did the trick, first disable the constraint, then update, then insert.

Answer (score 0):

Use a trigger (on TABLE_A) to create the row in TABLE_B.

For example (assuming you are using a SEQUENCE to generate the PK)

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_TABLE_A_AI
 AFTER INSERT
 ON TABLE_A
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE_B VALUES (SEQ_TABLE_B.NEXTVAL, :NEW.ID);
END;
```

Comment: I want to do it one time only, as part of a migration script and not permanent.